# create additional polylines from existing polylines

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I'm looking for a way to fill out a polygon area with additional polylines that are offsetting the originals that maximize the line length whenever possible up to a certain distance (ie, the line cannot be longer than 20,000 feet). Below is an example showing the original polylines and new polylines I've added manually..I also know the new lines are perfect but wanted to provide an example that i'm after.

Original
[image: original]

Additional Lines Manually Drawn
[image: additional]

example data output

```
original<-
structure(list(Name = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(-121.435466639, 
-121.411553056, 46.3509518230001, 46.284564861), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-121.400131643, 
-121.37621806, 46.3552348530001, 46.288847891), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-121.419405278, 
-121.395491695, 46.3627301560001, 46.296343194), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-121.387282554, 
-121.425472903, 46.218891737, 46.1799875500001), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-121.376931899, 
-121.415122248, 46.2138948690001, 46.174990682), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-121.363368972, 
-121.401559321, 46.2128241120001, 46.1739199250001), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-121.485435321, 
-121.47722618, 46.2895617290001, 46.224959362), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-121.497213653, 
-121.489004512, 46.289204811, 46.224602444), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-121.507564309, -121.499355168, 
46.289204811, 46.224602444), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
"LINESTRING", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "NAD27", 
    wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"NAD27\",\n    DATUM[\"North American Datum 1927\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"Clarke 1866\",6378206.4,294.978698213898,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4267]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -121.507564309, 
ymin = 46.1739199250001, xmax = -121.363368972, ymax = 46.3627301560001
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Name = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

```
new_lines<- structure(list(Name = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(-121.423331386, -121.399417803, 46.297413949, 
    46.2310269870001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.420832953, -121.412623812, 46.2738572860001, 
    46.2313839070001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.43046977, -121.422260629, 46.2745711250001, 
    46.2320977460001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.440463507, -121.432254366, 46.2717157720001, 
    46.229242393), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.450814163, -121.442605022, 46.2720726910001, 
    46.220319412), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.406556186, -121.382642603, 46.2838510220001, 
    46.2174640600001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.389424067, -121.365510484, 46.286706376, 
    46.2203194140001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.37586114, -121.351947557, 46.286706376, 
    46.2203194140001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.416193005, -121.454383354, 46.2406638030001, 
    46.2017596160001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.40584235, -121.444032699, 46.234239259, 
    46.195335072), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.396562452, -121.434752801, 46.2274577960001, 
    46.1885536090001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.465090929, -121.456881788, 46.288490971, 
    46.2238886040001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.474370827, -121.466161686, 46.290275567, 
    46.2256732000001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.47686926, -121.452955677, 46.330250511, 
    46.2638635490001), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.462949413, -121.43903583, 46.3370319750001, 
    46.270645013), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg")), structure(c(-121.450457243, -121.42654366, 46.3448841970001, 
    46.278497235), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
    "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "NAD27", 
    wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"NAD27\",\n    DATUM[\"North American Datum 1927\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"Clarke 1866\",6378206.4,294.978698213898,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4267]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -121.47686926, 
ymin = 46.1885536090001, xmax = -121.351947557, ymax = 46.3448841970001
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Name = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

```
polygon<- structure(list(Name = NA_character_, geometry = structure(list(
    structure(list(structure(c(-121.376931899, -121.401202402, 
    -121.4272575, -121.455454112, -121.464020172, -121.473656989, 
    -121.487576836, -121.501496683, -121.510062743, -121.512918096, 
    -121.515059611, -121.516844206, -121.516844206, -121.513631934, 
    -121.498284411, -121.478296938, -121.453669517, -121.434395883, 
    -121.419048359, -121.393707099, -121.377645738, -121.370864274, 
    -121.360870538, -121.353375235, -121.346236852, -121.344452257, 
    -121.348735286, -121.376931899, 46.1735630060001, 46.162855431, 
    46.1703507330001, 46.1853413380001, 46.1996181040001, 46.2085410830001, 
    46.213537951, 46.2185348190001, 46.2281716360001, 46.2431622400001, 
    46.2581528440001, 46.2856356190001, 46.3020539, 46.318115262, 
    46.3320351090001, 46.3459549560001, 46.356305611, 46.3630870750001, 
    46.365942428, 46.3630870750001, 46.3595178830001, 46.34845339, 
    46.3209706150001, 46.288847891, 46.2488729470001, 46.23067007, 
    46.2106825970001, 46.1735630060001), .Dim = c(28L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "NAD27", 
    wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"NAD27\",\n    DATUM[\"North American Datum 1927\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"Clarke 1866\",6378206.4,294.978698213898,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4267]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -121.516844206, 
ymin = 46.162855431, xmax = -121.344452257, ymax = 46.365942428
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(Name = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")))
```

Comment: what criteria are you using to define a 'filled polygon'? And how 'offset' does each line have to be. In your example drawing some of them are touching.

Comment: My criteria is somewhat obtuse, I want to efficiently fill the polygon. In this example 3,000 offset would work. thanks!

Comment: Could you do something like: Draw the bounding box, fill it with straigh lines running north-to-south (of the required length, then re-start a new line, until a line draws past the bounding box), then move east by 3,000, and repeat until you reach the east-most end of the box. Then crop all those LINESTRINGS by your polygon shape?

Comment: Possibly, my issue with drawing north to south is that that the lines are bearing/azimuth are not North/South. I'm trying to keep a similar bearing/azimuth as the original lines. Hope that makes sense.